# Wordpress. Как добавить свой сайдбар для каждой страницы?

Tags: wordpress, шаблоны

Как добавить свой сайдбар для каждой страницы и задать каждому сайдбару свои стили?
Спасибо.

В итоге нужно стилизовать для каждой страницы сайдбар по разному.
Я сделал так:

В файл functions.php дописал:
http://pastebin.com/Lghts1EM

Создал файл sidebar-home.php:
http://pastebin.com/aTiMQqAa|

В итоге, в админке, в разделе "виджеты" появился сайбар "Home". Я добавил в него некоторые виджеты, но на странице они почему-то не появляются.
Что я упустил?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Представляю вам мой пример добавления сайдбара.

В **functions.php**:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Футер на странице записи',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
    'after_title' => '</div>',
));
```

Мне нужно было добавить виджет внизу каждой страницы.

Код в **footer.php**:

```
<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Футер на странице записи")) : ?>
```

Мой виджет должен был показываться везде, кроме домашней страницы и страницы отдельной записи, поэтому полный код выглядит так:

```
<?php //Проверяем, что страница не является главной или является отдельной страницей  ?>
<?php if (is_front_page() === false OR is_single() === true): ?>
    <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Футер на странице записи")) : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Чтобы стилизовать ваш футер или виджет отдельно для каждой страницы, вам нужно конкретизировать стили. Wordpress добавляет к тэгу `body` уникальные классы для каждой категории записи, страницы или записи. Выглядит это примерно так:

[image: Вид в панели разработчика Google Chrome]

Разберем на примерах.
css для стилизации `custom-widget` на ВСЕХ страницах отдельных записей:

```
.single-post .custom-widget {
   background: darkorange;
}
```

только для категории с `id=191` и только если пользователь выполнил вход:

```
.category-191 .logged-in .custom-widget {
background: #faa;
}
```

По аналогии с этими примерами вы можете сами написать практически для любой страницы.
Надеюсь, это вам поможет. Удачи.